# Como concatenar valores dentro de uma class em React.JS

Tags: react, concatenação-de-string

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
{
    this.state.listSkills.map(function(habilidade){
    return (
        <ul className="habilidades">                                            
            <li className="habilidade-"{habilidade.value}>
                <h2>{habilidade.name}
                <div className="barra"><span></span></div>
                </h2>
            </li>
        </ul>
        );
    })
}
```

O valor da variável `habilidade.value` vem de um json dinâmico com um valor e um simbolo de porcentagem (`%`), exemplo: `10%`.

Preciso concatenar a string `"habilidade"` com essa variavel e tirar o `%` para que fique `class="habilidade-10"`. Como fazer?

Comment: Onde exatamente você precisa desse valor?

Comment: no sass, para que eu possa usar quando ele for renderizado

@for $i from 0 through 100{
                li.habilidade-#{$i}{
                    .barra{
                        span{
                            width: 1% * $i;
                        }
                    } 
                }

Comment: Tente `className={"habilidade-" + habilidade.value.replace('%', '')}`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Criei uma resposta para ajudar outros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema futuramente. Se puder, marque-a como correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em react, você pode utilizar códigos javascript dentro das propriedades dos componentes utilizando as chaves (`{}`).

Isso é muito útil quando você precisa concatenar valores ou chamar funções.

Com isso, para concatenar o `"habilidade-"` com o `habilidade.value` na propriedade `className`, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
className={"habilidade-" + habilidade.value}
```

Para tirar o valor de `%` você pode dar um replace na string, ficando assim:

```
className={"habilidade-" + habilidade.value.replace('%', '')}
```